# Large blue smudges when printing in color, no smudges in black

Tags: printer, laser-printer

I refilled the toner in my Samsung CLP-365 today. When I print in black only there is no problem. When I print a page where anything is in color, huge smudges appear, always blue. Could this be that I overfilled the toner? I removed half the toner from blue. Still smudges.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's applicable to the Samsung printers but at my work when our Lexmarks do that it means that we need to clean the nozzle of the cartridge or the printer heads. Give that a go first

Comment: Could you tell me what part of it is the "nozzle" and "head"?

Comment: btw it is a laser printer.

Answer (score 1):

As a) only Cyan is giving problems, and b) as far as I can see on the web, there are no separate drums involved, I would start by replacing the Cyan cartridge.